# How to use convolution 1D with lstm ?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have time series data input 72 value by separate last 6 value for test prediction. I want to use CONV1D with LSTM.

This is my code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('D://data.csv',
             engine='python')

df['DATE_'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_']) + MonthEnd(1)
df = df.set_index('DATE_')
df.head()

split_date = pd.Timestamp('03-01-2015')

train = df.loc[:split_date, ['COLUMN3DATA']]
test = df.loc[split_date:, ['COLUMN3DATA']]

sc = MinMaxScaler()

train_sc = sc.fit_transform(train)
test_sc = sc.transform(test)

X_train = train_sc[:-1]
y_train = train_sc[1:]

X_test = test_sc[:-1]
y_test = test_sc[1:]

###################  Convolution  #######################

X_train_t = X_train[None,:]
print(X_train_t.shape)
X_test_t = X_test[:, None]

K.clear_session()
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(6, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(12,1)))
model.add(LSTM(6, input_shape=(1,3), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(3))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam' )

model.summary()

model.fit(X_train_t, y_train, epochs=400, batch_size=10, verbose=1)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test_t)
```

When I run it show error like this

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (None, 12, 1) but got array with shape (1, 64, 1)
```

How to use conv1D with lstm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is between your input data and your input shape.

- You said in the model that your input shape is `(12,1)` (= `batch_shape=(None,12,1)`)
- But your data `X_train_t` has shape `(1,64,1)`.

Either you fix the input shape of the model, or you fix your data if this is not the expected shape.

For variable lengths/timesteps, you can use `input_shape=(None,1)`.

You don't need an input_shape in the second layer.

Comment: I change model to Conv1D(1, 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(None,1))). It have no error. If I use Conv1D(6, 3, It show error  InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): computed output size would be negative. Why I can not set kernel size to 3 ?

Comment: You need something with length >= 3 to have a kernel size = 3. Have you changed your input data?

Comment: Are you using `channels_first` in your keras config file?