# How do I combine a CNN and an LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am quite new to the concept of LSTM and CNN. So, I have defined my LSTM and CNN separately currently:

**LSTM:**

```
def create_basic_rnn_model(config, output_size):      
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50,batch_input_shape=(config.BATCH_SIZE,config.LOOK_BACK,32),
                   return_sequences=False, stateful=config.STATEFUL, dropout=0.5, activation="softsign"))     
    model.add(Dense(output_size, activation="sigmoid"))
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

**CNN:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(time_steps//subsample, 32, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=48, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(strides=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(84, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
```

**Data Input Based on Config:**

```
class Config(object):
    #data are downsampled, each 15th data point is taken
    DOWNSAMPLING = 15
    LOOK_BACK = 35
    BATCH_SIZE = 512

    #Iterations on stateful model, epochs on non-stateful
    EPOCHS = 30
    ITERATIONS = 1
    STATEFUL = False
    SHUFFLE = not STATEFUL
    VERBOSE = 0
```

**Where Model will be Trained:**

```
def train_rnn(subjects, labelToTrain, trainSeparateLabels, config, modelGenerator, callbacks): 
    #Calculating output size of trained model
    LabelsRange = [labelToTrain,labelToTrain+1]
    if(not trainSeparateLabels):
        LabelsRange = [0,6]
    OutputSize = LabelsRange[1] - LabelsRange[0]     
    #Model creation
    model = modelGenerator(config, output_size = OutputSize) 
    
    #Training
    for i in range(config.ITERATIONS):
        #For specified subjects
        for subject in subjects:
            #For series 1-7 
            for j in range(1,8):
                signals, labels = load_train_data_prepared(subject = subject,series = j) 
                #Create sequences
                X_train_signals, X_train_labels = create_sequences(
                    None,
                    None,
                    signals.iloc[::config.DOWNSAMPLING].values,
                    labels.iloc[::config.DOWNSAMPLING].values,
                    look_back=config.LOOK_BACK       
                )        

                X_train_labels = X_train_labels[:,LabelsRange[0]:LabelsRange[1]]
                croppedSize = math.floor(len(X_train_signals)/config.BATCH_SIZE)*config.BATCH_SIZE        
                #Train model on relevant label (calling fit repeatedly in keras doesnt reset the model)
                model.fit(
                    X_train_signals[0:croppedSize],
                    X_train_labels[0:croppedSize],
                    epochs=config.EPOCHS,
                    batch_size=config.BATCH_SIZE,
                    shuffle=config.SHUFFLE,
                    verbose=config.VERBOSE,
                    callbacks=callbacks
                )            
                if(config.STATEFUL):
                    model.reset_states()
    
    
    print("FITTING DONE")
    return model, LabelsRange
```

How would I combine my LSTM and CNN please? I have searched up several ways but none of them work. I have searched up ConvLSTM2D but I can't seem to connect them together. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For time series data (where you would use 1D convolutions), it's common to first use convolutions to extract features from the signal, followed by recurrent layers to learn a temporal pattern of those features, and ending with some fully-connected layers to match your desired output shape. I imagine the process would be largely the same with 2D convolutions.

Comment: Thanks for this response. Could you please help me out in regards with my code? I don't know how to connect the layers.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your inputs are time series, you should use Conv1D:

   model = Sequential()

   model.add(Conv1D())

   model.add(LSTM())

   model.add(Dense(softmax))
2. If your inputs are sequences of images or videos, you should use ConvLSTM2D.

Comment: So I will not be able to use ConvLSTM2D in my case then?

Comment: Also I don't think you can just add Conv1D and LSTM like that surely?

Comment: What kind of input are you using? Time series, images, videos?

Comment: These answers suggests that we can use that architecture: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344610/how-to-setup-1d-convolution-and-lstm-in-keras and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261170/how-to-use-convolution-1d-with-lstm

Comment: time series ---

Comment: i am using time series

Comment: So you can use Conv1D + LSTM + Dense.